# Can 'Thrust' generate random numbers on the device

Tags: cuda, thrust

Does anybody know if the CUDA library 'Thrust' can generate random numbers on the device? I've seen from the example codes that it can do it on the host...But Thats no good for me really.  Cheers in advance
Jack

Comment: If you're not aware of it, the usual way of generating sort of-random numbers on a GPU is Perlin noise.

Comment: @JerryCoffin: isn't Perlin Noise a way of turning random numbers into "texture", rather than a random-number generator?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, Thrust has device random generator. See [Monte Carlo](http://code.google.com/p/thrust/source/browse/examples/monte_carlo.cu) example provided by Thrust team.

Answer (score 0):

cuRAND might also do what you want: http://developer.nvidia.com/curand
It's not Thrust, but it has similar functionality.