# Cuda filling array in GPU

Tags: cuda

i want to fill my arrays on GPU side:

in order to do that :

First i created arrays for host side and device side:

```
int *d_A = NULL;
int *h_A = NULL;
```

then i allocate memory for host array:

```
h_A = (int *)malloc(numOfData*sizeof(int));
```

and then i allocate for device array:

```
cudaMalloc((void **) &d_A, numOfData * sizeof(int));
```

and then i pass the d_A to the gpu side

```
cudaMemcpy(d_A, h_A, numOfData, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
```

and call function

```
  generateVector<<<1,2>>>(d_A,numOfData);
```

generate function is below:

```
_global__ void generateVector(int * d_Data,int count) {

    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        d_Data[i] = rand_from_0_to_100_gen();
    }
}
```

I know GPU side does now allow me to use rand function to fill my array. What can i do then? What is the possible solution?

Comment: Here's [an example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15247522/cuda-random-number-generation/15252202#15252202) showing how to create random numbers on the GPU.  Note that in that particular case, each thread generates the same random sequence, but this is easily changeable by passing a different seed perhaps based on `threadIdx.x` to each thread.

Comment: Also, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11024718/can-thrust-generate-random-numbers-on-the-device

Comment: Please edit your existing question rather than adding a new one.

Answer (score -1):

I believe, by far the easiest way for you would be to use [CURAND](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/curand/index.html) library. You can find some samples in CUDA SDK - take a look at Monte-Carlo ones.